# How to print Turkish day/month names with Time.strftime on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, strftime, turkish

Is there anyway that i can use locale on ruby's Time.strftime ? How can i use different languages? German, Turkish anyother language rather than English? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [R18n internationalization](http://r18n.rubyforge.org/) gem has locale-aware pretty printers that can print dates and times in various languages and formats.

Comment: hmmm ruby doesn't support locale then? need extra gem to make this happen. strange. thanks gioele.

Comment: The classes in the standard Ruby library completely ignore locales because that is a problem that is very hard to solve correctly for everybody. Go for that gem, it is solid and widely used.